# How can this error be handled while trying to add an hdf file to QGIS as a raster layer through its in-built Python console?

Tags: raster, gdal, qgis-python-console

I have downloaded a file named "MOD13A2.A2015033.h25v08.061.2021319043521.hdf" to my Downloads folder (I am running my QGIS on Windows) and wrote the following code:

```
raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer("C:/Users/My Name/Downloads/MOD13A2.A2015033.h25v08.061.2021319043521.hdf","project","gdal")
print(raster_layer.isValid())
if not raster_layer.isValid():
    print("error summary:", raster_layer.error().summary())
```

It turns out, the variable "raster_layer" above is not valid, and its associated variable "isValid()" is False. The error message being output is as follows:

```
error summary: Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: C:/Users/My Name/Downloads/MOD13A2.A2015033.h25v08.061.2021319043521.hdf
```

I checked my GDAL version and its 3.7.1. I also checked whether the path to the file is correct and with the os library of python the path does turn out to be correct.

I also tried to add the hdf file directly through the "Add Raster Layer" option in the "Layer" menu of QGIS and it does work. However, it's only when I try to add it in an automated way through the Python console with the above code that I encounter the above problem.

Where is the code going wrong and how do I correct it?